# WiX Toolset Overriding exit dialog causes compile error

Tags: xml, wix

I'm trying to fix the checkbox background issue in the exit dialog by writing my own exit dialog. However, no matter what I try, I can't get it to compile.
In the end I always get the error `ICE82: This action MyExitDialog has duplicate sequence number -1 in the table InstallUISequence` and the same for `AdminUISequence`. I've seen numerous examples of people implementing their own dialogs with install sequences. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I'm using WiX Toolset v3.10

My Exit Dialog:

```
<Fragment>
  <UI>
    <Dialog Id="MyExitDialog" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.ExitDialog_Title)">
      <Control Id="Finish2" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUIFinish)" />
      <Control Id="Cancel2" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Disabled="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)" />
      <Control Id="Bitmap2" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="234" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.ExitDialogBitmap)" />
      <Control Id="Back2" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Disabled="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
      <Control Id="BottomLine2" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
      <Control Id="Description2" Type="Text" X="135" Y="70" Width="220" Height="40" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.ExitDialogDescription)" />
      <Control Id="Title2" Type="Text" X="135" Y="20" Width="220" Height="60" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.ExitDialogTitle)" />
      <Control Id="OptionalText2" Type="Text" X="135" Y="110" Width="220" Height="80" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Hidden="yes" Text="[WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT]">
        <Condition Action="show">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT AND NOT Installed</Condition>
      </Control>
      <Control Id="OptionalCheckBox2" Type="CheckBox" X="139" Y="206" Width="13" Height="13" Hidden="yes" Property="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX2" CheckBoxValue="1">
        <Condition Action="show">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT AND NOT Installed</Condition>
      </Control>
      <Control Type="Text" Id="OptionalCheckBoxText2" Width="190" Height="17" X="154" Y="206" Text="[WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT]">
        <Condition Action="show">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT AND NOT Installed</Condition>
      </Control>
    </Dialog>
  </UI>
  <InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="MyExitDialog" OnExit="success">1</Show>
  </InstallUISequence>
  <AdminUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="MyExitDialog" OnExit="success">1</Show>
  </AdminUISequence>
</Fragment>
```

My UI:

```
<Fragment>
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
  <UI Id="MyWixUI">
    <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Segoe UI" Size="9" />
    <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Segoe UI" Size="12" />
    <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Segoe UI" Size="9" Bold="yes" />
    <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
    <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="InstallDir" />
    <DialogRef Id="WelcomeDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="DiskCostDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="VerifyReadyDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
    <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
    <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
    <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />
    <DialogRef Id="MyExitDialog" />
    <DialogRef Id="BasicFeatureDlg" />
    <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="BasicFeatureDlg" Order="0">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="BasicFeatureDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="1">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="BasicFeatureDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="1">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="BasicFeatureDlg" Order="2">NOT Installed</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="2">Installed</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
    <!--<Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>-->
    <Publish Dialog="MyExitDialog" Control="Finish2" Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX2 = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
  </UI>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was a bug on my end. Apparently the following was nested within my Publish list which referenced it causing the ICE error. Once I changed it to `Dialog="MyExitDialog"`, everything compiled and my new exit dialog worked! I guess the previous version was referencing `ExitDialog`.

```
<Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>
```